# Changing an expression to string

Tags: ocaml

I need to convert an arithmetic sequence that uses
this type:

```
type expr =
      VarX
    | VarY
    | Sine of expr
    | Cosine of expr
    | Average of expr * expr
    | Times of expr * expr
    | Thresh of expr * expr * expr * expr
```

here are the definitions for all the things in it:

```
e ::= x | y | sin (pi*e) | cos (pi*e) | ((e + e)/2) | e * e | (e<e ? e : e)
```

need to convert something like this:

```
 exprToString (Thresh(VarX,VarY,VarX,(Times(Sine(VarX),Cosine(Average(VarX,VarY))))));;
```

to this:

```
string = "(x<y?x:sin(pi*x)*cos(pi*((x+y)/2)))"
```

I know I have to do this recursively by matching each expr with its appropriate string but Im not sure where the function begins matching or how to recurse through it.  Any help or clues would be appreciated

Comment: Matching might be the wrong way to think of it. Your input is already laid out as a tree with a specific structure. You just need to traverse the tree. OCaml patterns are just a nice way to describe what to do for each kind of component.

Comment: I kind of understand what you are saying, Im guessing the Varx and Vary are leaves of the tree and the functions are nodes, but im not sure how the syntax in Ocaml works to traverse a tree and change each part to strings.  Can you provide an example or link me one of something similar?

Comment: Again it's probably better to think of calculating a new value than of changing anything. The values you're working with are immutable. A natural progression might be this: how to calculate length of a list? How about the height of a tree? How about the height of an `expr`? Then concatenate strings at each level (with additional syntax) instead of just carrying along the maximum height.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version of what you probably want:

```
type expr = 
  | VarX
  | Sine of expr

let rec exprToString = function
  | VarX -> "x"
  | Sine e -> "sin(" ^ exprToString e ^ ")"

let () = print_endline (exprToString (Sine (Sine (Sine (Sine VarX)))))
```

It recurses over the AST nodes and create the string representation of the input by concatenating the string representations of the nodes.

This approach may not work nicely for bigger real world examples since:

- String concatenation `(^)` creates a new string from two, this is slower than using some more appropriate data structure such as `Buffer.t`
- Too many parentheses, ex, `(2*(2*(2*2)))`, not `2*2*2*2`. If you want minimize the number of parentheses, your algorithm must be aware of operator precedence and connectivity.